# Excel: How to change column to average based upon unique identifier

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-365, average

I have a situation where for a certain daily date range I have 5 different columns of data which are for 5 different pieces of equipment. I'm trying to set up a calculator where I can select the piece of equipment and a date range, and it will average the correct column. Averageif based on date range is easy, but I don't know how to get the column to average to change, based on a reference cell.

The data set will continually expand (additional rows) as time passes, so it is dynamic.

Any help would be appreciated. Below is a bit of a 'pictoral'

Columns:              A,             B,             C,              D,              E,              F,

Column Headers:  Date Range,        TR1,           TR2,            TR3,            TR4,            TR5,

User enters equipment to view in Cell E1

Scenario 1: Cell E1 reads "TR2" - Average TR2 (column C) based on Date Range (column A)

Scenario 2: Cell E1 reads "TR5" - Average TR5 (column F) based on Date Range (column A)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SU. Could you edit your post and paste an image of your data (or some representation of your data). It's a little hard to tell what you're trying to do at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

*Since you have not shared any screen shot, therefore I'm assuming dates for the calculation.*

- To get AVERAGE between dates the simple on is AVERGAIFS.

  ```
  =If(E2="TR2, AVERAGEIFS(C2:C20, A2:A20, ">=01/01/2020", A2:A20, "<=05/10/2020"),AVERAGEIFS(F2:F20, A2:A20, ">=01/01/2020", A2:A20, "<=05/10/2020"))
  ```

*Or you may use this also:*

```
=IF(E21="TR2",AVERAGE(IF((A2:A20>=G1)*(A2:A20<=G2),C2:C20)),AVERAGE(IF((A2:A20>=G1)*(A2:A20<=G2),F2:F20)))
```

*Where G1 is start date & G2 is ed date.*

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*